# How do I setup a puma.rb file in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, puma

Ok, I'm trying to setup Docker to an existing rails app.
I'm following a guide, but the guide uses a Unicorn server. I need to use Puma.

Assuming my /Dockerfile looks like this:

```
 FROM ruby:2.3.1
 RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev 
 postgresql-client
 ENV RAILS_ROOT /var/www/outtAttendance
 RUN mkdir -p $RAILS_ROOT/tmp/pids
 WORKDIR $RAILS_ROOT
 COPY Gemfile Gemfile
 COPY Gemfile.lock Gemfile.lock
 RUN gem install bundler
 RUN bundle install
 COPY config/puma.rb config/puma.rb
 COPY . .
 EXPOSE 3000
 CMD bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
```

What would my config/puma.rb file look like?

File tree is

```
 /MyApp
  /app
  /config
    /containers
      -puma.rb
 -Dockerfile
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure Puma normally:

```
# Puma can serve each request in a thread from an internal thread pool.
# The `threads` method setting takes two numbers: a minimum and maximum.
# Any libraries that use thread pools should be configured to match
# the maximum value specified for Puma. Default is set to 5 threads for minimum
# and maximum; this matches the default thread size of Active Record.
#
threads_count = ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 }
threads threads_count, threads_count

port ENV.fetch("PORT") { 3000 }

# Specifies the `environment` that Puma will run in.
environment ENV.fetch("RAILS_ENV") { "development" }

# Allow puma to be restarted by `rails restart` command.
plugin :tmp_restart
```

Don't forget to add `PORT`, `ENV` and `RAILS_MAX_THREADS` to your `docker-compose.yml` configuration file on the `environment` node.